# Does Japanese make the distinction between "-ing" and "-ed" adjectives?

Tags: comparative-linguistics

In English and other similar languages, there is usually a clear distinction between adjectives that describe things that create a certain sentiment and adjectives used to describe that sentiment itself, for example "tiring" vs "tired", "embarrassing" vs "embarrassed", "deadly" vs "dead", "enviable" vs "envious", "shameful" vs "ashamed"... However, I know that there are certain languages that do not always make this sort of distinction, and I've noticed that there seems to be a couple of adjectives of this type in Japanese too. I'm still in rather early stages so I can't say definitely whether this is the case or not.

Comment: Which Japanese adjectives do you think behave in this way? It might be easier to tackle it from that angle instead.